# Finding summary statistics. Struggling with having anything work after importing data into R from Excel

Tags: r, statistics

Very new to R here, also very new to the idea of coding and computer stuff.

Second week of class and I need to find some summary statistics from a set of data my professor provided. I downloaded the chart of data and tried to follow along with his verbal instructions during class, but I am one of the only non-computer science backgrounds in my degree program (I am an RN going for degree in Health Informatics), so he went way too fast for me.

I was hoping for some input on just where to start with his list of tasks for me to complete. I downloaded his data into an excel file, and then uploaded it into R and it is now a matrix. However, everything I try for getting the mean and standard deviation of the columns he wants comes up with an error. I am understanding that I need to convert these column names into some sort of vector, but online every website tells me to do these tasks differently. I don't even know where to start with this assignment.

Any help on how to get myself started would be greatly appreciated. Ive included a screenshot of his instructions and of my matrix. and please, excuse my ignorance/lack of familiarity compared to most of you here... this is my second week into my masters I am hoping I begin to pick this up soon I am just not there yet.

the instructions include:

```
# * Import the dataset
# * summarize the dataset,Compute the mean and standard deviation for the three variables (columns): age, height, weight
# * Tabulate smokers and age.level data with the variable and its frequency. How many smokers in each age category ?
# * Subset dataset by the mothers that smoke and weigh less than 100kg,how many mothers meet this requirements?
# * Compute the mean and standard deviation for the three variables (columns): age, height, weight
# * Plot a histogram
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the eventuality that your professor did not provide you with any materials to review and learn how to do those steps in R, I would recommend that you go through this book: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/ Specifically, chapters 3 to 5 to start.

Comment: immediately went to the link, already incredibly helpful. We did get assigned the Book of R as a text book, but without knowledge of what exactly I am even trying to do, the book felt overwhelming. thank you for the link it is much more digestible material!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow is not a place for homeworks, but I feel your pain. Let's get piece by piece.

First let's use a package that helps us do those tasks:

```
library(data.table) # if not installed, install it with install.packages("data.table")
```

Then, let's load the data:

```
library(readxl) #again, install it if not installed

dt = setDT(read_excel("path/to/your/file/here.xlsx"))
```

Now to the calculations:

1 summarize the dataset. Here you'll see the ranges, means, medians and other interesting data of your table.

```
summary(dt)
```

1A mean and standard deviation of age, height and weight (replace age with the column name of height and weight to get those)

```
dt[, .(meanValue = mean(age, na.rm = TRUE), stdDev = sd(age, na.rm = TRUE))]
```

2 tabulate smokers and age.level. get the counts for each combination:

```
dt[, .N, by = .(smoke, age.level)]
```

3 subset smoker mothers with wt < 100 (I'm asuming non-pregnant mothers have NA in the gestation field. Adjust as necessary):

```
dt[smoke == 1 & weight < 100 & !is.na(gestation), .N]
```

4 Is the same as 1A.

5 Plot a histogram (but you don't specify of what variable, so let's say it's age):

```
hist(dt$age)
```

Keep on studying R, it's not that difficult. The book recommended in the comments is a very good start.

Comment: thank you so much for your compassion and help with my question. I know stack overflow is usually not the place for homework questions so I was anxious to post, but I am so thankful to be able to get through this assignment. I've now arranged to arrive early to my courses with this professor so we can break things down slower for me moving forward. i WILL learn R this semester!

Comment: When an answer really answers your question, it is considered polite around here to mark it as "solution", by using the check mark below the answer's voting buttons. Keep on studying R, there's a lot of power on it!